What programming language was used in Frank Rubin's letter about Dijkstra's "Go To Statement Considered Harmful"?
The Wikipedia article about the famous "Go To Statement Considered Harmful" by Edsger Dijkstra also links:

an article from a Frank Rubin that tries to "debunk" harmfulness of Go To
and a later letter from Dijkstra commenting on that article.

I would like to know which computer language Frank Rubin is using in his letter.

Note, there's a second question regarding Dijkstra's Reply:
What programming language was used in Dijkstra's response to Frank Rubin's article about "Go To Statement Considered Harmful"

Never knew there was another "debunking" besides Knuth's micro-optimization masterpiece "Structured Programming With go to Statements" (Knuth, 1974).  Actually, not so much a debunking as a plea for considering the matter carefully in performance-critical code so as to not throw out the go to entirely but to reserve it for those situations where it was really useful.  And, basically, to be careful when programming and think things through because that's the right way to do the job.

P.S. - look at the 3 quotes Knuth used at the head of the article.  Third quote is priceless!  I used to love reading Knuth papers back then:  Well-written and the timely flash of excellent humor!

@davidbak Also, an early example of clickbait titling, another way Knuth was ahead if his time. "Before beginning a more technical discus-
sion. I should confess that the title of this
article was chosen primarily to generate
attention."

@davidbak Interesting article. It seems to be the source of the 'premature optimization' quote that is so popular. I was a little confused by the example being discussed because the solution seems so obvious until I looked it up and realized Algol 68 doesn't have a break statement. Eventually he gets to that exact limitation.

It's plain Pascal.
Plain Pascal as in no specific dialect. Nicely shown by either of the three programs:

(Snippet taken from p.196 of Communications of the ACM, Volume 30/3, 1987)

The most prominent giveaway is use of writeln (Write Line) to output a message.
Second is the assignment operator :=. While already introduced by IAL (a.k.a. ALGOL), Pascal was the most widespread language using it.
All three examples are also showing only Pascal keywords.
Last but not least, in the 1980s, Pascal was the Go-To language for programming, thought to be the final thought, especially in education.


"Pascal was the Go-To language for programming" Pun intended? as Pascal (and other lesser known Wirth languages) was probably THE language that tried to do its best to not use GOTO :-p

@chthon "Doing its best" is overrated. As a structured programming teaching tool, Pascal would have benefitted from break and continue included in the language from the start, rather than as a Turbo Pascal afterthought, apropos

To be more specific, it was the language used in most CS101 curricula for decades, and the language used in the Computer Science AP tests until 1999.

@LeoB. My recollection is that, at the time, any sort of "escape from middle of loop" was regarded with suspicion as just another use of goto (as in "goto endOfLoopLabel"). It took some time to realize that "if(end condition) { change loop variable to quit loop }" was never going to be elegant, and that break and continue, were more readable, etc... in practice.

My CS courses in college in the late 70s/early 80s all were pushing Pascal as the be all and end all language. Meanwhile in the aerospace engineering courses we used only Fortran and when I started my job as a NASA contractor it was all Fortran.

@LeoB.: Agreeing with T.E.D. and Owen Reynolds: it was doing its best. I actually never programmed in Turbo Pascal, only in implementations that followed Wirth. And its type system was also too strict. You had to use strings of all the same size, even the literals (padded out with spaces if necessary - but that could be that specific implementation).

@chthon The implementation I used, which deviated from Wirth with regard to escaping loops, had the same string size issue, requiring padding, e. g. see the third example. To be fair, implementing break/continue or analogs only takes a few lines in the compiler, and implementing strings requires on the order of scores of extra lines in the compiler, and hundreds in the runtime library.

@LeoB. It should not be ignored that 'pure' Pascal was intended support teaching by minimizing concepts and removing any ambiguity. This was not only important for streamline teaching of programming concepts but also teaching about compiler design, maybe the topic he's most known for back then. Having strict data types helped to greatly simplify compiler writing, while only fixed size types (including strings) allowed a lean runtime. That way students could write their first single pass within a comparable short course and  without much bootstrap support (I still have the booklet ... somewhere

@Raffzahn That is true, but an industrial version of the language was in order as soon as it started gaining popularity outside of the academia. That order was only fulfilled by Turbo Pascal.

@LeoB. Yes, there's nothing wrong by extending and improving the language - in fact, every other student I knew at the time did start to improve his compiler one way or another. None the less, above exchange is an academic one about principles, not really general improvement.

It looks like Pascal. That was then a widely use language.

Was it that widely used in 1974?  It is only places that had CDC computers that could run it and here weren't that many.

@cup Rubin's article was published in 1987

My bad - I was looking at Knuth's reply: not Pascal bit.
